# How can I see if a machine tried to connect to my (linux) server or not?

Tags: java, linux, client, network-connection

I am trying to connect to a linux server which has several listening ports, and my connections are failing (According to my client) because the "host is down" ... however, I know the host is up.

So is there a script or log file I can change/inspect to see the rejected connection on the server side ... better yet, see WHY the connection is failing  ?

In general, I find that connection failures can have misleading or ambiguous error messages... So I think this will solve my connection debugging activities once and for all, so that I will be able to directly test if the end point is rejecting a connection on the actual server side, rather than guessing based on client error messages.

BTW this is related to hadoop.

Comment: Have you tried using a packet sniffer such as tcpdump?

Answer (score 2):

Use tcpdump.

This site has a lot of examples, one of which will suite your needs -> http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/283/simple-usage-of-tcpdump/

I would start with:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 tcp port XXXX
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for "tcpdump -w test.pcap -i eth10 port 50070" ... ?

Comment: @jayunit100. You should run this command on a listening server. Looking at you command I see 2 outliers. `eth10` interface ( usually it will be eth0, or eth1, in the event that you are testing on a network gateway server you may have interfaces with higher numbers ).  Also, the port number is unusually high.  Basically it's in `DYNAMIC` range, which is usually a port assigned to a client connection by the OS.

Comment: "port assigned to a client connection by the OS." --- what does that mean ? Thanks... This is helping me....

Comment: @jayunit100. OK, here is TCP in 10 lines or less. Both client and server communicate through IP address and PORT pair.  Server establishes a listening service on a well known port ( e.g. 80 for HTTP, 25 for SMTP, 443 for HTTPS, etc. ). But client also need a port to receive replies from the server.  This port is assigned by the underlying TCP stack when client is making connection to the server. The port number for these purposes is usually assigned from this range [49152–65535]

Comment: @jayunit100. Looks to me that you need to read a book on networking.  This book 'TCP/IP Network Administration, Third Edition' by Craig Hunt from O'Reilly is a good start -> http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002978.do. Read at least first 3 chapters, you may even just browse them from the link above.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a firewall issue. If you're on Ubuntu, run `sudo ufw disable` and try connecting again. If you can connect, then enable ufw again: `sudo ufw enable` and add a rule to allow incoming connections on the port you want.

*source*: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: tried. didnt work, but good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try iptables, for example:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "New Connection: "
iptables -I OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "New Connection: "
```

And then look into server logs - call 'dmesg' from shell.

Comment: Thanks.  What is iptables doing ?  does it simply see everything on every network interface ?